# RealmList serialization issues (Realm/Gson/Intent)

Tags: java, android, serialization, realm

I use Retrofit, Gson and Realm in my project. 
I have this class `Example`that need to be `Serializable`. Without Realm I'd write it like that :

```
public class Example implements Serializable {
    @SerializationName("users")
    private List<String> users

    //... getters and setters
}
```

Realm comes into play and `Example` becomes (note that getters and setters are this way for compatibility reasons) :

```
public class Example extends RealmObject implement Serializable {

    @SerializedName("users")
    private RealmList<RealmString> users;

    public ArrayList<String> getUsers() {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RealmString rs : users) {
            array.add(rs.getValue());
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<String> users) {
        RealmList<RealmString> array = new RealmList<>();
        for (String rs : users) {
            array.add(new RealmString(rs));
        }
        this.users = array;
    }

}
```

with RealmString being :

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    private String val;

    //Constructors, getter and setter
}
```

and add a custom Gson type converter for it to be deserialized correctly :

```
public class RealmStringRealmListConverter implements JsonSerializer<RealmList<RealmString>>,
        JsonDeserializer<RealmList<RealmString>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(RealmList<RealmString> src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
        for (RealmString tag : src) {
            ja.add(tag.getValue());
        }
        return ja;
    }

    @Override
    public RealmList<RealmString> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                              JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        RealmList<RealmString> tags = new RealmList<>();
        JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement je : ja) {
            if (je.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                tags.add(new RealmString(je.getAsString()));
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }

}
```

Ok so now we're starting to feel that Realm is starting to have to big of an impact over our code. But that's a side problem, the main issue is that Example is no longer Serializable : RealmList isn't.

so I tried to make the RealmList transient and have its pendent List that I can annotate with @Ignore, and recreate the RealmList after serialization. But transient is not accepted by Realm.

Now I feel a bit stuck, `Example` is passed through intents in numerous parts of my code (it's a member of a lot of classes). I don't want to use an id and query it everywhere.

My question would be :

How can I change ̀ Example` in a way that allows me to do `new Bundle().putSerializable("test", new Example());` without crash.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You'll not be able to pass any realm object via intents. You'll have to pass an ID and query. Exactly as you said you didn't want to do. It's just how it works. Also; What's your question???

Comment: Ok my question would be, how to do that in a way that my code would remain unchanged outside of `Example`, ie that I could do ```new Bundle().putSerializable("example", new Example())``` without a crash. I update my question

Comment: As per my comment. You'll only be able to do it if you don't use Realm. RealmObjects are live objects with direct connection with the Realm DB. Normally you don't even really access the object you created, but during compilation, the Realm plugin generates a proxy object that extends from your object and what u're really using is that proxy object. Just give a try to log `Realm.getInstance().querySomething().getClass().getCanonicalName();` and you'll see it's not your actual objects anymore.

Comment: But can't I override Serializable's serialisations methods to store by id and then query it ? my main issue is that transient makes realm unhappy

Comment: So if I use Realm, I'll never be able to store objects via onSaveInstanceState bundle to store my objects, I'll have to change all this behaviour ?

Comment: as far as my understand of Realm goes. You better change your app behavior to pass on intent or save onSavedInstanceState just `IDs` and query the DB engine on runtime. OR don't use Realm.

Comment: This is days of work, maybe weeks. That might be what will stop me from using Realm. I'll think about it, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you **migrating** to Realm? In new code, I'd just advise you to send the ID and then requery the object where needed. RealmProxies are not serializable and not parcelable, and creating unmanaged copies of them is kinda the opposite of how Realm works. `I don't want to use an id and query it everywhere.` that's the general Realm way, yeah

Comment: Although you can try using `realm.copyFromRealm()` to create detached copies, and detached copies are serializable; BUT you lose auto-updates and you have random copies lying around while using a zero-copy database

Comment: Yes I'm migrating to Realm, and I start to see that It comes with a different way of doing things. I'll have to adapt a bit, I just didn't imagine that my code would change this much.

Comment: Ah, yeah, in that case I can see why it would seem like a headache. To understand why it's this way - it's because Realm is a zero-copy database, and parcelling creates a copy. However, I think you **can** actually parcel to a Bundle (as mentioned previously) if you use `Parcelable`, although I think in that case you should consider using [Parceler](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler) in conjunction with [RealmListParcelConverter](https://gist.github.com/patloew/bc32a2a1a3c0097e9c7020192fb2c78f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serializable` won't work with `RealmList`, but you can use [Parceler library and implement Parcelable](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler)
 to parcel RealmObjects (note: it will turn them into unmanaged copies!)

```
@Parcel(implementations = { UserRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { User.class })
public class User extends RealmObject {
    // ...
}

compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.3"
apt "org.parceler:parceler:1.0.3"
```

To [parcel RealmList, use following code](https://gist.github.com/patloew/bc32a2a1a3c0097e9c7020192fb2c78f)

```
/* Copyright 2016 Patrick Löwenstein
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License. */

public class RealmListParcelConverter implements TypeRangeParcelConverter<RealmList<? extends RealmObject>, RealmList<? extends RealmObject>> {
  private static final int NULL = -1;

  @Override
  public void toParcel(RealmList<? extends RealmObject> input, Parcel parcel) {
    if (input == null) {
      parcel.writeInt(NULL);
    } else {
      parcel.writeInt(input.size());
      for (RealmObject item : input) {
        parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(item), 0);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public RealmList fromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
    int size = parcel.readInt();
    RealmList list = new RealmList();

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      Parcelable parcelable = parcel.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
      list.add((RealmObject) Parcels.unwrap(parcelable));
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: As for string lists, consider storing them into a single String field instead of as a list of objects.

Comment: I am a newbie to realm, I am integrating realm as cache database/local DB. I have models for regular use and to manage Realm Representation.

Comment: I am thinking of adding arraylists as serialized strings is it a good approach as I haven't found any tutorial for Realm lists.

Comment: `I am thinking of adding arraylists as serialized strings is it a good approach as I haven't found any tutorial for Realm lists.` for primitives yes, for RealmObjects no

Comment: Thanks!,  
Also is it a good approach for having two models, I came across your answer where you were suggesting to have a different model for the realm object, rather than regular data models. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I typically had a model for the API that was separate from the RealmObjects. But I did use RealmObjects directly for the UI. Tbh the new frozen RealmResults are theoretically a nice solution if someone has a background looper thread for the Realm query evaluations.

Comment: They might be better But, I had a already developed project. I used volley cache That works fine. The old Models show not serializable if I use realmTypes in'em.

Answer (score 0):

I made a `SerializableRealmList` that could be used in place of the `RealmList`. This way, the list could be serialized by `ObjectOutputStream`.

```kotlin
class SerializableRealmList<E> : RealmList<E>(), Serializable {

    private fun readObject(inputStream: ObjectInputStream) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        addAll(inputStream.readObject() as List<E>)
    }

    private fun writeObject(outputStream: ObjectOutputStream) {
        outputStream.writeObject(toList())
    }
}
```